# command line indicator in JTextArea

Tags: java

I've made a `JTextArea` where I input different commands and separate them by newline `"\n"`, and if there is an error in one of the lines then I write it in a console output. Here I made a very simple, and not the best solution to make this line indication, but it's a bit buggy.

[image]

**How I made it**

I've defined a `textArea` where I can type different information/commands, and if one of the commands/lines is invalid I write it in the console just to display something for now. I basically count the lines by splitting the `textArea` rows up by `"\n"` and then count which line the error occurs in, and the left `consoleLineNum` is using the amount of rows in `textArea`, to then make a string containing all the numbers of `rows+"\n"`.
**But here my question is**, is this a good enough way? If so, why/how can I make it more robust? Or how can I make this indication with line numbers, in the left? It has to increase each time the user makes a new line in the `textArea`.

```java
private static void createAndShowGUI() {    

    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(3,3));

    /*----- Panels -----*/
    JPanel panel1       = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2       = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3       = new JPanel();

    //Add Components to this panel.
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    JScrollPane scrollPaneOutput = new JScrollPane(consoleOutput);
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    consoleOutput.setEditable(false);
    consoleLineNum.setEditable(false);
    ButtonPanel_listener(buttonPanel);

    textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                consoleLineNum.setText("");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(textArea.getText().split("\n").length)); i++) {
                    sb.append(i + " \n");
                }
                consoleLineNum.setText(sb.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }
    });

    //Background
    panel1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    //Preferred size
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

    panel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel2.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel2.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panel2.add(consoleLineNum, BorderLayout.WEST);
    consoleLineNum.setText(num);

    panel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel3.add(drawCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel1.add(scrollPaneOutput, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //textArea.addActionListener(e -> drawCanvas.drawCircle(250, 250, 200));

    //Add contents to the window.
    frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(panel3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

**Difference between your expected and actual results**

When I hit newline/Enter, it doesn't show the number right away, only when I start typing.

[image]
Or
[image]

Here I want it to match where the user is, so if the user hit enter, and go to the next line, then the number matches and is shown right away.

If I delete all lines, except some, it still shows the numbers

[image]

Here I want it to wipe all the numbers and update it to match the amount of data in `textArea`.

Tried this, and it works almost as expected. The only problem is that when I delete lines, it's one behind.

```java
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    numI = textArea.getLineCount();
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && numI > 0) {
        numI = numI - 1;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= numI; i++) {
            sb.append(i+1 + " \n");
        }
        consoleLineNum.setText(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to listen for changes in the text of the [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html). The API of `JTextArea` already provides a method that tells you how many lines it contains, namely `getLineCount()`. After placing the `JTextArea` in a [JScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), set a [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) as the *row header* for the `JScrollPane`.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class CountLns implements DocumentListener, Runnable {
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JList<Integer>  lineNumbersList;
    private JTextArea  textArea;

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent docEvent) {
        // Never called.
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent docEvent) {
        handleDocEvent();
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent docEvent) {
        handleDocEvent();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    private JScrollPane createTextArea() {
        textArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);
        textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        lineNumbersList = new JList<>(new Integer[]{1});
        lineNumbersList.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        lineNumbersList.setFont(textArea.getFont());
        lineNumbersList.setFixedCellHeight(16);
        JViewport rowHeader = new JViewport();
        rowHeader.setView(lineNumbersList);
        scrollPane.setRowHeader(rowHeader);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private void handleDocEvent() {
        DefaultListModel<Integer> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        List<Integer> lineNumbers = IntStream.range(0, textArea.getLineCount())
                                             .boxed()
                                             .map(i -> i + 1)
                                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
        model.addAll(lineNumbers);
        lineNumbersList.setModel(model);
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTextArea(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        textArea.requestFocusInWindow();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new CountLns());
    }
}
```

Whenever the contents of the `JTextArea` change, the `DocumentListener` counts the lines in the `JTextArea` and sets the `JList` model to contain exactly that number of elements. So if the `JTextArea` has 12 lines, the `JList` will contain all the numbers from 1 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
 yourTextArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        // Returns true every time the user presses either backspace or enter.
        if (e.getKeyChar() == '\n' || e.getKeyChar() == '\b') {

            int lines;
            
            // Checks if the text ends with a newline, if so,
            // it adds 1 to the line count, so that would make your line
            // appear even if the user just started a new line.
            if (yourTextArea.getText().endsWith("\n")) {
                lines = yourTextArea.getText().split("\n").length + 1;
            } else {
                lines = yourTextArea.getText().split("\n").length;
            }

            // Removes previous count.
            linePanel.setText("");

            // Appends a new line to the area for every line.
            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
                linePanel.append((i + 1) + "\n");
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried to make another solution myself, can you look at that :) cant make yours work

Answer (score 0):

*I did not write in Java for 1 year so sorry, if I messed up syntax*

First of all, why won't you implement line wrap and line count increment by pressing Enter? It looks much more simple to me

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        textArea.append("\n"); 
        Integer lineCount = Integer.parseInt(consoleLineNum.getText());
        Integer newLineNumber = new Integer(lineCount.intValue() + 1)
        consoleLineNum.append("\n" + newLineNumber.toString())
    }
}
```

However you still will not get actual number of lines, if some of them will be deleted. So you can also add trickier logic to your `keyPressed()` method

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) {
    // Well I actually googled this line for counting occurences
    Integer linesCountActual = textArea.getText().split("\n", -1).length - 1);
    Integer linesCountLeft = consoleLineNum.getText().split("\n", -1).length - 1);
    if (linesCountActual > linesCountLeft) {
        String oldText = consoleLineNum.getText();
        String newText = oldText.substring(0, oldText.length() - 2);
        consoleLineNum.setText(newText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to make another solution myself, can you look at that :) cant make yours work